# Can a 125mw dual gang pot handle 10w audio output?

Tags: audio, resistance, electricity

I want to build balance control for two audio amplifier circuits, and I want to use dual gang pot.

I want to know if I connected it directly to the outputs of the two audio amplifiers circuit then to the speakers if the the resistance go to about 0 ohm will it be ok for 10W output.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off connecting it to the amplifier inputs?

Comment: I don't know I connected volume control to amplifier inputs but I want to know what will happen in this case

Comment: 125mW = 0.125W...

Comment: But the potentiometer has high resistance I think it will drop the power of 10w

Comment: No, it'll burn out pretty rapidly.

Comment: If it drops the power down to 125mW you're kind of defeating the purpose of your amplifier, anyway.

Comment: "But the potentiometer has high resistance" - but you haven't specified a resistance. What impedance are your speakers?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know if I connected it directly to the outputs of the two audio amplifiers circuit then to the speakers if the the resistance go to about 0 ohm will it be OK for 10W output.

No.

- Potentiometers are usually rated at 0.125 W.
- The maximum current the pot can handle is given by \$ P = I^2 R \$ which can be rewritten as \$ I = \sqrt {\frac {P}{R}} \$. If you choose, for example, a 100 Ω potentiometer then \$ I = \sqrt {\frac {0.125}{100}} =  35 \ \text {mA}\$.
- With an 8 Ω loudspeaker this would give you about \$ P = I^2 R = 0.035^2 \times 8 = 0.01 \ \text W \$ from you speaker.

The correct way to reduce speaker volume is to reduce the amplifier **input** signal level using a potentiometer.